# Passing a custom event in a Laravel Blade View

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have a PHP blade file and I have a list of components working as they but can't seem to pass in a custom event in the kebab style casing the documentation mentions .

**Blade template**

```
<div id="app">
     <Shop
        :active-tab="activeTab"
        @show-product-modal="handleShowProductModal"
     >
     </Shop>

</div>
```

Even the `@show-product-modal` color syntax in my text editor shows something is off but I can't tell what the issue is here.  I've even tried camel casing it but that doesn't do it either.  However, if i changed it to 1 word , like "@showitnow", it works fine.

---

Comment: Please can you show the code where you're emitting the event?

Answer (score -1):

When using VueJS you can't use kebab case for listening to component events. Instead your blade template should read:

```
<div id="app">
     <Shop
        :active-tab="activeTab"
        @showProductModal="handleShowProductModal"
     >
     </Shop>

</div>
```

Comment: It's the other way round. You get a warning if you use camelcase in html as html is case insensitive. Also, you can use either if you're using `.vue` files :)